# People cannot "Like" any posts on my Facebook Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

On my Facebook page, the "Like" and "Comment" option is missing on all posts on my wall. I can like and comment on my own page, but others cannot. I discovered this when I went to my profile page and clicked on the "View As" option.

If I share a link, or someone posts a picture or message on my wall a viewer of my page does not have the option to "Like" or comment on anything. People can only view my profile but cannot do much else unless they post actual content to my wall.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

Check your privacy settings: https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy

Click on `How You Connect` `Edit Settings`. Look at the `Who can post on your timeline?` if it's set to `Only Me` this will allow people to see your posts, but not be able to do anything with it.

*Edit* You also cannot see the link or comment buttons when you're looking at your page as someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that, when you post something on Facebook, the post is for which audience, like there are options - Friends, Close Friends, Only Me. Make it public, may be in that way, your problem get resolved.

Other than this, might be your privacy setting are not compatible, you have to change that, there is a complete guide on that. Check out here :

http://www.techlicious.com/tip/complete-guide-to-facebook-privacy-settings/